# ASIHTTPRequest download: Should I request a large file or many small size files?

Tags: ios, http, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest library for my iOS project. My app is about download a ebook (with 150+ jpg files). I have two options:

1. Zip all images and just request a single zipped file (around 200MB).
2. Request images each by each (it will become 150+ requests).

Which option is the best if I have more than 1000 users request the ebook simultaneously each day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an 100% answer to your question, but speaking from experience, I believe you will find it helpful.

I did a somewhat similar app once where I was supposed to update (redownload) a very large number of xml files (up to a couple of thousands).

The one-by-one method was rather slow but with a good `NSOperation` and `NSQueue` management, it worked ok, with no UI freezes or crashes on the first iPad. I believe it took me at most 15-20 minutes for the max number of files (somewhere over 5000 operations, with 5 concurrent downloads each), on wifi connection.

When I tried the zip method, to see if it would be faster / better, it made the iPad 1 crash due to high memory usage. And the zip size was about 100 mega if I remember correctly

I would suggest you to go with the first option. 1000 requests per day is not such a high number and this way the user doesn't have to wait for the whole archive to be downloaded, but can read the already downloaded pages without delay.

Comment: Dear BBog, Thx for sharing your experience. :)